# Can't connect to internal website from Lan

Tags: wordpress, xampp, host

I can't connect to my internal website from Lan. I'm using windows 7 and installed XAMPP. Then, I installed wordpress and run it locally. My ip address is `192.168.2.39`. When I called `127.0.0.1/mysite` ,everything was ok. But another computer from Lan can't access website successfully. I type `192.168.2.39/mysite` in browser,the errors occur. So, I go to network connection and edit no proxy setting for `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.2.39`. And then, I view `192.168.2.39/mysite`, the website was shown.But the website didn't show website completely. When I clicked menu, the website loaded a few second and the error show me that can't connect to `127.0.0.1`. I want to fix it. From local computer, the website is Ok, but requesting from others computer, the webpage show me error. How to fix it ?. Please, help me. I want to host internal wordpress website in Local Area Network and want to access from any computers within in LAN.

Comment: what is Listen's value in httpd.conf

Comment: In httpd.conf , listen's value is 80

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html).

You'll probably need to do the following:

```
Stop the XAMPP server, if it is running already.
Open the file [XAMPP Installation Folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf.
Search for the string *Listen 80 *
Change this 80 to 192.168.2.39:80.
Now save and re-start XAMPP server and you are done.
```

Also add exception for xammp in firewall if your firewall is enabled.